# Android repeating Alarm Manager sets off immediately

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

**TL;DR** - AlarmManager  .setRepeating is starting immediately instead of the desired future time.. (for example 5 minutes from now)

So basically I am starting an alarm manager and i'm giving it the time left to operate and for some reason it is firing instantly.. the user is choosing a time from a time picker, and I set this time for the next alarm.
code below:

-this method get's the time left until the alarm, this is used as the triggerInMillis for the alarmManager.

```
    /** calculate the time left until the alarm with calendar */
private static long getTimeFromCalendar(final int hourOfDay, final int minute) {

    Date dat  = new Date();//initializes to now
    Calendar cal_alarm = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal_now.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.setTime(dat);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,hourOfDay);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    cal_alarm.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

    if(cal_alarm.before(cal_now)){
        cal_alarm.add(Calendar.DATE,1);
    }

    long calAlarm = cal_alarm.getTimeInMillis();
    long calNow = cal_now.getTimeInMillis();

    long timeLeft = (calAlarm - calNow);

    return timeLeft;
}
```

then I call the -startAlarm- method :

```
private static void startAlarm(final Enums typeToStart) {

    final PendingIntent pendingIntent = GBAlarms.createPendingIntent(OnAlarmReceiver.class, Constants.typeEnum, typeToStart);
    final long timeToAlarm = Utils.getTimeToAlarm(typeToStart);
    long repeatTime = Constants._24hours;

    GBAlarms.createRepeatingAlarm(timeToAlarm, repeatTime, pendingIntent);
}
```

and finally, my -GBAlarms.class- where i create my alarms and pending intents.

```
public class GBAlarms {

    /** Define our AlarmManager */
    private static AlarmManager mgr = (AlarmManager) BaseApplication.getAppContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    /** Create a new PendingIntent */
    public static PendingIntent createPendingIntent(final Class destination, @Nullable final String extra, Enums.TeaType type) {
        Intent i = new Intent(BaseApplication.getAppContext(), destination);
        if (extra != null && type != null) { i.putExtra(extra, type); }
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(BaseApplication.getAppContext(), type.getValue() , i, 0);
        return pi;
    }

    /** Create a new repeating Alarm */
    public static void createRepeatingAlarm(final long time, final long repeatTime, final PendingIntent pi) {
        mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, time, repeatTime, pi);
    }

}
```

I don't understand, for some reason the alarm pops right when I set it in the -createRepeatingAlarm- method, and I debugged of course, the time parameter looks legit.. if I set it to 3 minutes, 10 minutes, it puts that time left in the trigger..

can anyone spot my mistake? maybe I'm missing something?

thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: would something like : mgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + repeatTime, repeatTime, pi)  work better?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a "pending" alarm, 
a alarm that repeats after a specific interval.

The trick is to cancel the current alarm in the moment you are starting.

Look at the code below: You have to call the method getBroadcast with the 
flag `PendingIntent.CANCEL_CURRENT`

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr;
PendingIntent pendingIntent;

public void startAlarmManager()
    {
         Intent dialogIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class);
              alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
              pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, dialogIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

              alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, pendingIntent);

          }
    }
```

Comment: I kinda have to disagree with your answer. I don't have a current alarm at the moment. first, I always cancel alarms before calling a new one, 2nd, its also happening when i just installed so 100% no current alarm

Answer (score 0):

why are you using ELAPSED_TIME?

please try using RTC_WAKEUP and switch

```
long timeLeft = (calAlarm - calNow);
```

with just calAlarm

you don’t need to mills left, you need the mills that you want it to pop.